# How to PUT only some fields with Restangular?

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, restangular

Let's say I have a resource with several fields, and some of them are read-only. Or maybe they belong in different use cases that I would like to handle differently on the server.

For instance, my `bing` resource looks like this:

```
{id: 1,
 foo: "A", 
 bar: "B", 
 createdAt: "2013-05-05"}
```

I would like to get Restangular to PUT only some fields, executing requests like:

```
PUT /bing/1 {foo: "A"}
PUT /bing/1 {bar: "B"}
PUT /bing/1 {foo: "A", bar: "B"}
```

What I do **not** want to do is:

```
PUT /bing/1 {id: 1, foo: "A", bar: "B", createdAt: "2013-05-05"}
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 22):

I'm the creator of Restangular.

@Nicholas is absolutely right :). That's a PATCH and not a PUT. And Restangular does support it :).

`elem.patch({foo: 2})` would be the way to go if elem is already a `restangularized` object.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 6):

That's a `PATCH` not a `PUT`.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789

Comment: Interesting. How do I achieve what I need with Restangular then, even with PATCH?

Comment: I have never heard of Restangular before so I can't help you there. Perhaps write your own routine if the framework doesn't support it? Perhaps you can extend the framework to support `PATCH`?

Comment: Well, this is a question specifically about Restangular. Learning the difference between `PATCH` and `PUT` is useful and thank you for it, but I'm still looking for a Restangular answer.

Comment: @KonradGarus Oh of course, that's fair enough. I came across the question via a different tag.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to pass the entire object to the patch method, including all the fields that you don't want to send to the backend, and then use a request interceptor to delete any unwanted fields before the request is sent.

For example, to always delete the field `createdAt` from any patch request you could do something like

```
app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
  RestangularProvider.setRequestInterceptor(function(element, operation, route, url) {
    if (operation === 'patch') {
      delete element.createdAt;
      return element;
    } 
  });
});
```

To learn more about request interceptors see the documentation on [setRequestInterceptor](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#setrequestinterceptor)

Comment: I find that this method is sometimes cleaner, allows me to simply stuff JS objects into other JS objects and send them w/ Restangular, without muddying all the code with concerns about which particular fields should go over the network.